# Firebase add users but disable any modification

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

got stuck on this problem: I want to allow user to register on my webpage using firebase, for that reason I planned the following structure:

```
users : {
    user0 : { //user specific data },
    user1 : { //... }
    ...
}
```

Everything works fine (writing, reading...) until I change the security rules. I want to change them because I want the users only to register and not to have the power to delete their or potentially other user accounts. But I couldn't find anything very helpful on that. Below is what I'm currently left with:

```
{
"rules": {
    "users" : {
          ".read": true,
          "$uid" : {            
          ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
       }
    }
}
}
```

I'm wondering how to set up the rules such that users can **only** add new accounts.

I would appreciate any help!

Thaanks :)

Edit: Here's what I wanted to achieve with the rules above, maybe the below example using the simulator will make my point clear.

The first thing, I want to do is, is to let a user register at the /users node. Therefore, I chose the Custom Auth point in the simulator:

{ provider: 'anonymous', uid: '002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386' }.

Now, if I choose "simulate write" and give the path /users and the following key-value pair:

{ "002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386": { "1" : {"a" : "b"}}}

I get the below message (see Result_2), which tells me, that I cannot write to /users because there's no write rule allowing it, which I totally understand in the above security rules configuration, but I don't know how to change them such that I am able to write key-value pairs as the above one while still allowing each user to write on there entry **only**. I.e. the user with the uid: 002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386 would be allowed to write on the corresponding value with the rules above as long as he is authenticated (see Result_1).

E.g. Custon Auth authenticated user writing ON HIS ENTRY: (WORKS PERFECTLY AS EXPECTED)

{ provider: 'anonymous', uid: '002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386' }.

As the previous time. Now, "simulate write" on path:

/users/002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386

Result_1:

Attempt to write {"4":{"name":"fred"}} to /users/002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386 with auth={"provider":"anonymous","uid":"002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386"}

/

/users

/users/002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386:.write: "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid" => true

Write was allowed.

Result_2: Writing the user onto the /users nodes fails, i.e. no registering is possible. And I want here to be able to add a user to /users but not be able to modify/delete user from /users. See simulator output below.

Attempt to write {"002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386":{"1":{"a":"b"}}} to /users with auth={"provider":"anonymous","uid":"002a448c-30c0-4b87-a16b-f70dfebe3386"}

/

/users No .write rule allowed the operation.

Write was denied.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions cascades - once you give a user a permission on `/users` you cannot remove that permission on `/users/$uid` anymore.

The solution is to only grant permission on the lowest level, so in your case:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users" : {
        ".read": true,
        "$uid" : {
          ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, but with that nobody can write to /users (tried it on simulator with custom auth mode). So, how should I then add a uid to /users ? Further, since ".read": true other each user can read stuff from other users which should not be the case either :(. I honestly don't get why firebase didn't choose to put rules on CRUD operations, but that's another story...

Comment: With my `.write` rule anyone can write to their own specific node. If you authenticate the simulator with `uid` `Tukk` and then write to `/users/Tukk` it will be allowed.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but only if the node Tukk already exists. If it doesn't exist, there is no possibility to create it besides logging in as Admin on firebase and do it manually, however, I want to let the users register themselves on /users. Sorry, if I didn't point that out clearly.

Comment: Firebase automatically creates a path when you write a value to it. You don't need permission on the path, just on the value(s) you're writing. If something doesn't work for you: edit your question to include the location that you're writing to in the simulator, the value that you're writing, the rules that you have and the output the simulator gives you.